# AVFoundation camera tutorial

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Is there a basic tutorial for the AVFoundation for use with the camera anywhere?

UIImagePicker isn't the right tool for my app and it looks like this is but I'm not sure how to get it going.

I can kind of see how to take a picture using AVCaptureStillImageOutput but I can't see how to display the camera view onto the screen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're a registered Apple developer, session 409 (in the Graphics and Media section) of this year's WWDC is a very good tutorial: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

here are more direct links ...

session 409:

http://adcdownload.apple.com//videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_409__using_the_camera_with_av_foundation.mov

also, session 405 intro:

http://adcdownload.apple.com//videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_405__discovering_av_foundation.mov

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Just registered last night with the dev program and I didn't know anything about these tutorials!

If I could give you +2 votes I would :D

Thanks

Comment: Great top thanks. I threw in the direct links, cheers