# Use the x-ray or thermal effect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera

How would I go about changing camera effects in the same way that Photo Booth on the Mac or iPad changes from x-ray to thermal effect? I have searched all over and can't find anything at all. I would like to use the x-ray or thermal effect.

This is what I have been trying but I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
UIImagePickerController *Camera_Picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
Camera_Picker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:Camera_Picker animated:YES];
Camera_Picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(CGAffineTransformMake(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1));
```

I have been change around the numbers but nothing works right it just turns the screen white. When you invert something in Photoshop it gives it a thermal look, that is my thought process.

Comment: "This is what I have been trying but I have no idea what I'm doing" - doesn't fill prospective answer posters with confidence...

Comment: Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html Look through the list of the Core Image filters. One of them probably does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You've seen the word 'Invert' and just assumed that it does what you want. It doesn't, sorry :(

The transform that you're applying to to affect the layout of the camera, it's nothing to do with the actual colours displayed. You're turning the camera preview upside down (and probably putting it somewhere off screen, hence the white display).

There's no sdk option to do what you're trying to do as far as I know - you will have to read in each frame of the camera and convert it yourself. This is something that the camera picker class won't let you do.

You'll need to look at the AVFoundation classes to do this - they're a bit more complicated. A starting point [is the reference docs from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) and [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643445/avfoundation-camera-tutorial) is probably useful as well!

Comment: Thank you for your information I found what I was looking for. I need to use core image from core video.